# Como migrar una base de datos de XAMPP a Laragon

Tags: xampp, migration, laragon

estoy intentando migrar una base de datos desde XAMPP a LARAGON, y al intentar hacerlo con el comando que viene en la página de Laragon, el cual es el siguiente:
mysqldump.exe --all-databases > C:\laragon\tmp\alldb.sql me aparecía el siguiente error:
**mysqldump.exe: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'mi user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" when trying to connect**
estuve buscando y al fin encontre la solución la cual la dejo en la sección de respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

La solución al anterior problema es:
ejecutar el mismo comando que aparece en la página de Laragon pero agregando el usuario y password con el que te quieres conectar ejemplo:

> **Para una base en específico:*
> **mysqldump.exe mi_base_datos -u root -p > C:\laragon\tmp\mi_base_datos.sql**
> **Todas las bases:
> **mysqldump.exe --all-databases -u root -p > C:\laragon\tmp\alldb.sql**

Answer (score 0):

1. Abrir XAMPP Control Panel e iniciar el servicio MySQL, enseguida abrir la ventana Shell.
2. Ejecutar `mysqldump.exe --all-databases -u root -p > C:\laragon\tmp\alldb.sql` presionar `enter`.
3. Detener los servicios de XAMPP y cerrar presionando el botón `Quit`.
4. Abrir Laragon e iniciar servicios `Iniciar todo`.
5. En la ventana de Laragon ubicar y `Abrir Terminal`.
6. Dentro de la terminal escribir `mysql -u root -p` Presionar `enter`.
7. Escribir `< C:/laragon/tmp/alldb.sql` (slash normal, no invertido) presionar `enter`.
8. Escribir "quit" y presionar Enter para salir de mysql y enseguida cerrar la consola.

Ya deberías tener las bases de datos importadas y podrás verlas en
Bases de Datos de la ventana de Laragon.